# Negative margins, float and Firefox

Tags: css, margin

Hello I have a website that you can see by visiting http://alterego.im/user-wassgha , I want the profile image of the user and the content to be overlapping. The solution am using works perfectly on chrome but doesn't on firefox. Can you please tell me what's wrong with it? (By the way, if you have any suggestions to improve the website please tell me)

Comment: Could you elaborate? The profile pic is overlapping the angry bird perfectly in FF?

Comment: The problem is that the overlapping is messing up the sidebar and content under them (the sidebar moves to the right making the content go under it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try a `clear:both;` on the sidebar element (`.span3`) then.

Comment: Well, using clear both it ignores the margin-top:-100px; on the #testimonials and that's not how I exactly want it :/

Comment: ..and if you remove the `margin-top:-100px;` on `#testimonials` your layout works again. Find another way to put the whole content on top, perhaps higher up in the HTML tree?

Comment: Is there any way to keep exactly the same layout but make it working on firefox?

Comment: Sure, but I don't know exactly what you have done that breaks in FF, chrome and FF is similar in its rendering. Make it work in FF and chrome should behave similar.